# Can i get Active directory users info such as email, Telephone & Manager using UserPrinciple

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, userprincipal

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc5 web application:-

```
List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, ADusername, ADpassword))
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();



                foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
                {
                  {
                    DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
                    dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
                    dc.UserPrincipalName = p.UserPrincipalName;
                    dc.Name = p.Name;
                    dc.SamAccountName = p.SamAccountName ;
                    dc.DistinguishedName =     p.DistinguishedName;

                    results.Add(dc);
```

i am able to get these AD info such as Display Name, Name, etc but can i also get these info using the above code:-

- email address.
- Telephone.
- Manager

Thanks?

Comment: Here's an article on how to do it,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr

Comment: thanks for the reply, the link mentioned that VoiceTelephoneNumber & emailaddress are within the UserPrincipal properties. but i can not access them in the same way as for the Name,DisplayName, etc.. can u advice ?

Comment: Yeah you are not using a UserPrincipal, you are using a Principal, which is the base class of UserPrincipal.  You need to case p to UserPrincipal to access the properties on UserPrincipal.

Comment: @Ryios can you provide some example how to do so please ? and if i case to UserPrinciple will i still be able to access the current values such as SamAccountName, username , etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need the username, first, last and the smtp.
If you have them, here's the code:

```
var adService = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry());
    adService.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=LOGON))";
    adService.PropertiesToLoad.Add("FirstName");
    adService.PropertiesToLoad.Add("LastName");
    adService.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SMTP");
    return adService.FindOne();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, so i need to change my original code "var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context))" to be "var adService = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry());" ?? and will i be able to get the old properties such as DisplayName, SamAccountName , et/...

Answer (score 1):

Below I have updated your existing code to use a UserPrincipal.

```
List<UserPrincipal> results = new List<UserPrincipal>();
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, ADusername, ADpassword))
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
                foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
                {
                  {
                    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = p as UserPrincipal;
                    if (userPrincipal != null)
                        results.Add(userPrincipal);
```

And here I have added code to show you how to get the additional properties you need at a higher level.

```
//Get information you need from UserPrincipal..
var matchingUsers = results.Where(p => p.DisplayName.ToLower() == "bob");
foreach (var matchedUser in matchingUsers)
{   
  string telephone = matchedUser.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
  string email = matchedUser.EmailAddress;
  var directoryEntry = matchedUser.GetUNderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
  string manager = directoryEntry.Properties["manager"] as string;
}
```

Comment: your code worked perfectly but the only problem is that the Manager will be saved as "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection" for all users not sure why ?

Comment: The manager field is probably coming back as supporting multiple users (e.g. a person can have multiple managers), so you just need to loop through the values of the PropertyValueCollection and get the one you want.